# pass string as function input argument in matlab

Tags: matlab

I need to generate different block diagonal matrices like:

`blkdiag(0,0,0, ... ,0,unit)`

`blkdiag(0,0,0, ... ,0,unit,unit)`

.

.

.

`blkdiag(unit,unit, ... ,unit,unit)`

in say 100 iterates and evaluate them with `unit` being a `m*m` matrix. I generate the string of the argument in a loop, however function does not understand char input and I don't know what to do!

any help is appreciated ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`blkdiag` wants numeric values as inputs in a comma-separated list. An easy way to generate a comma-separated list is using cell arrays.

I assume that by "100 iterates" you mean that you're passing 100 values to `blkdiag`, with the first call being 99 zeros and one instance of `unit`, and the last call being 100 instances of `unit`.

```
unit = magic(5);   % some random test matrix for unit
total_iterations = 100;   % total number of iterations to go through
C = cell(2*total_iterations-1);     % total size of cell array
C(1:total_iterations-1) = 0;
C(total_iterations:end) = unit;
for iter = 1:total_iterations
   new_matrix = blkdiag(C{iter:iter+total_iterations-1});
   % do other stuff here...
end
```

`C{a:b}` generates a comma-separated list of the elements of `C`, which is just what we need.

Comment: thank you ... cell is exactly what i needed ... didn't know about it ...